# How do PCI express RAID cards work?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

I was recently playing with Xen server which supports hardware RAID only and as I always used Linux MD's only so far, I have no knowledge of hardware RAID at all. I was looking for some cheap hardware RAID solutions and I found PCI express cards with SATA controllers that claim to "support hardware RAID".

My question is, how would I manage these RAID arrays using these cards? In Linux there is mdadm for software RAID that easily allows me to manage it and even recover these arrays online with no reboot using terminal. But how would I assemble an array on that PCI express card? It isn't even a part of motherboard so I doubt there would be BIOS options for it.

Is it necessary to use some extra 3rd party software to manage RAID arrays while using these cards?

Is it possible to switch failed disks and rebuild the array online, without need to reboot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I work with SAS raid cards, and its pretty simple.

You have *multiple* 'bioses', with one per device which load up in sequence. Some of our work systems have 2, so we end up having 3 different sets of options we can set before the OS even starts.

You could have *multiple* raid cards and each loads up with its own bios options and you would configure the raid levels and 'virtual drives' there. Your OS would then see those 'disks' when it boots up.

This bios would have its own menu, with options to configure raid arrays, set up things like battery backups and so on.

You'd also have software tools in your client OS to manage things from the OS itself in addition, but real raid *should* let you set your disks up *without* an OS. I do believe *if* your raid was the right level, *and* it supported hotswap (and good raid should), you ought to be able to hotswap, and run some command to do a rebuild.

A *lot* of lower cost raid implementations, even on PCI cards are "fakeraid" and may not give you the best results ([serverfault has a question on this worth reading](https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid)) - specifically the comments to [chopper3's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/9426), and [Oskar Duveborn's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/9431)).

Comment: Excellent point about fakeraid. If the OP is looking for cheap RAID cards, most likely they won't be true hardware RAID.